# lwip supports multicast or broadcast

Tags: broadcast, multicast, lwip

In LWIP, it is confirmed that it supports multicast or broadcast but what will happen if the data or packet is sent by sender using broadcast? is there any mecanisms of ACK? is it so then at the sender side there will be problem of implosion..Please help me finding the issues that what will happen either it follows the ACK for reliablility or there is not ACK mechanism and reliability. How congestion control will be done in this protocol?

Comment: Multicast is usually sent in datagrams, so no ACK at the transport layer AFAIK